# Check if exists any path, in DI-Graph

Tags: python, graph, graph-theory

If i have a Di-Graph, how to check if all pairs (a,b) of nodes create a path?

Example:

Input:

```
v1 v2
v5 v6
v2 v3
v3 v4
v4 v5
v0 v1
```

And i need check if exist atleast one path through this graph, without visiting each node more then once.

[image]

I have already tried backtracking, but for biggest input it will took hours...

Specific example:

On input i have edges:

```
{m,a}, {a,c}, {a,m}
```

and i have to check, if there is a path, in this case it will return True, because exist

```
{a,m} -> {m, a} -> {a,c}
```

Comment: Your question is extremely ambiguous. Could you please clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: On input i have edges: {m,a}, {a,c}, {a,m} and i have to check, if there is a path, in this case it will return True, because exist {a,m} -> {m, a} -> {a,c}

Comment: Pick a pair from your list; look for another pair you can concatenate it to; if such a pair exist, pop both pairs, push their concatenation; if no such pair exists but there are at least two remaining distinct pairs, then no path exists.

Comment: Have you checked out the [simple path](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/simple_paths.html) functions from `networkx`?

Comment: Your example doesn't meet the requirement that each node is only visited once: `a` is visited twice.

Comment: @Timus in my example i have three words... amangam, malta, arcurc and i have to put them togehter to one string, so: amangamaltarcurc and in only need to know, if there is atleast one solution... I can not use any library

Answer (score 1):

### A relatively naive, quadratic algorithm

Pop a path from your list of path. Pop another path in the list to concatenate it with. Push the concatenated path back into the list. If at any time we cannot find another path to concatenate it with, it means the answer is no, all pairs of nodes do not combine into a single path, so we return `None`.

```py
def combine_into_one_path(list_of_paths):
  path = list_of_paths.pop()
  while list_of_paths:
    path2 = pop_adjacent_path(list_of_paths, path[0], path[-1])
    if path2 is None:
      return None
    elif path[-1] == path2[0]:
      path = path[:-1] + path2
    elif path2[-1] == path[0]:
      path = path2[:-1] + path
    else:
      assert(False)
  return path

def pop_adjacent_path(list_of_paths, a, b):
  for i,p in enumerate(list_of_paths):
    if p[0] in (a, b) or p[-1] in (a,b):
      return list_of_paths.pop(i)
  return None

print(combine_into_one_path([[1, 2], [5, 6], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [0, 1]]))
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

print(combine_into_one_path([[1, 2], [5, 6], [2, 3], [3, 7], [4, 5], [0, 1]]))
# None
```

This algorithm is quadratic in the number of paths because the `while`-loop in `combine_into_one_path` has one iteration per path in the list, and function `pop_adjacent_path` iterates through the list as well.

Note that this code doesn't check that nodes are unique; for instance, `[v1, v2, v3, v2, v4, v1, v5]` would be considered a valid path. You could add a check just before the final return in `combine_into_one_path` to make sure every element in the path is unique.

### Making it linear

What slow the algorithm down is having to iterate through the whole list to find a pair of nodes to combine our current path with. One way to avoid that would be to store the pairs in a dictionary, so we can answer the questions "does a pair end with `a`?" and "does a pair start with `b`?" in constant time.

```
def combine_into_one_path(list_of_paths):
  path = list_of_paths.pop()
  forwards = {p[0]:p for p in list_of_paths}
  backwards = {p[-1]:p for p in list_of_paths}
  while forwards:
    if path[-1] in forwards:
      p2 = forwards[path[-1]]
      del forwards[path[-1]]
      del backwards[p2[-1]]
      path = path[:-1] + p2
    elif path[0] in backwards:
      p2 = backwards[path[0]]
      del backwards[path[0]]
      del forwards[p2[0]]
      path = p2[:-1] + path
    else:
      return None
    print('\npath     =', path)
    print('forwards =', forwards)
    print('backwards=', backwards)
  return path

print(combine_into_one_path(['manta', 'alcats', 'random']))
# randomantalcats
```

This is almost the same algorithm, but we replaced function `pop_adjacent_path` with a dictionary check, which is constant time instead of linear.

Just to understand how the algorithm works:

```
list_of_paths = [[1, 2], [5, 6], [3, 4], [4, 5], [0, 1], [2, 3]]

path     = [2, 3]
forwards = {1: [1, 2], 5: [5, 6], 3: [3, 4], 4: [4, 5], 0: [0, 1]}
backwards= {2: [1, 2], 6: [5, 6], 4: [3, 4], 5: [4, 5], 1: [0, 1]}

path     = [2, 3, 4]
forwards = {1: [1, 2], 5: [5, 6], 4: [4, 5], 0: [0, 1]}
backwards= {2: [1, 2], 6: [5, 6], 5: [4, 5], 1: [0, 1]}

path     = [2, 3, 4, 5]
forwards = {1: [1, 2], 5: [5, 6], 0: [0, 1]}
backwards= {2: [1, 2], 6: [5, 6], 1: [0, 1]}

path     = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
forwards = {1: [1, 2], 0: [0, 1]}
backwards= {2: [1, 2], 1: [0, 1]}

path     = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
forwards = {0: [0, 1]}
backwards= {1: [0, 1]}

path     = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
forwards = {}
backwards= {}
```

Comment: It returns:     `del backwards[p2[-1]] KeyError: 100`

Comment: @MartinPoláček On which input?

Comment: @MartinPoláček this list of words has several words that start with the same letter or end with the same letter!! This is not like your question at all and would be a much harder problem