# Connecting multiple small strings into one long string

Tags: python

For example i have three strings:

```
manta
alcats
random
```

And i need to check, if is possible to connect this strings using first and last char to one long string. **And i can not use any library.**

In my example, it will return True, because it will be connected like:

```
randoMantAlcats
```

I tried backtracking, it works for small dataset, but for biggest one, it will took hours...

So im looking for good and fast algorithm.

Comment: I wanted to point out a duplicate, but it turns out the other question was asked by you as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64681887/check-if-exists-any-path-in-di-graph

Comment: @MartinPoláček--in the graph version of this problem you mentioned not being able to use any libraries.  You should add that constraint to this problem's description.

Comment: @DarrylG Added...

Comment: @MartinPoláček--when you mentioned trying backtracking but it was too slow, were you referring to this [algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hamiltonian-cycle-backtracking-6/)?

Comment: @DarrylG yes, yes

Comment: @DarrylG it tooks hours, when i have about 10 000 strings and the solution doesnt exist

Comment: @MartinPoláček--you probably should add that code, or at least a link to it in order to meet SO question guidelines.  Having code and showing you have done research reduces the chance of a question being downvoted.

Comment: @DarrylG my problem is, in each algorithm i need to defined start and end, but i dont know, which string is start and end...

Comment: @MartinPoláček--from [Hamiltonian path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem#Algorithms) which mentions the complexity of various algorithms for this problem, it appears it is time-consuming for a large number of nodes.

Comment: @DarrylG yea thats the problem, which i need to solve... Because i have new now 100 strings and it took about hour...

Comment: When I saw the title I instantly thought [DCGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar) but then upon reading the question saw that it was Python. When reading the problem saw `backtracking` and knew that you knew the correct way to solve this, but probably did not know the details for lack of experience. The reason `backtracking` is key is that this is a classic type of [Prolog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) problem, and Prolog has `backtracking` built-in. Also DCGs are a form of [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). Continued.

Comment: What would be interesting is to see this problem posted as [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic).  I would not be surprised if many saw this as a [dynamic-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info) problem. When solving this with Prolog one would probably use [tabling](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=tabling)

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem and took me longer than I expected, but I think I have something works. My code takes in a list of words and: (1) returns `False` if there's no solution, or (2) if there's a solution, returns a sequence of words where the last character of the previous word is the same as the first character of the last word.

Algorithm:

- First I make a list of all the first characters and a list of all the last letters. If there are more than one letter which are mismatched in this two lists, there's no solution
- Since all that matters are the first and last characters and everything in between doesn't matter, I make a dictionary where the keys are the first characters and the values are lists of last characters corresponding to the respective first characters. I think a dictionary improves efficiency because all the in-between characters doesn't matter i.e., 'sit' is the same as 'salt' and the same as 'sentiment', as far as the algo is concerned. So when you have a dictionary, if 'sit' doesn't work, you can skip testing all other 's----t' words
- Run backtracking algo on the list. If there's one single mismatched character between the list of first characters and list of last characters, I start with the mismatched first character; if there's no mismatched character between the two lists, I start with any first character

Here's the code, which I think works:

```
import string
import random
import timeit

def list_to_nodes(string_list):
    # convert list of strings into a dictionary where the keys corresponds to the first letters and the values corresponds to the last letters
    my_dict = {}
    for word in string_list:
        if word[0] in my_dict:
            my_dict[word[0]].append(word[-1])
        else:
            my_dict[word[0]] = [word[-1]]

    for value in my_dict.values():
        value.sort()

    return my_dict

def get_mismatches(string_list):
    # make two equal sized lists containing the first letters and last letters
    # if there are more than two letters which are different, this would not work
    start = []
    end = []

    for i in range(0, len(string_list)):
        start.append(string_list[i][0])
        end.append(string_list[i][-1])

    for char in start.copy():
        if char in end:
            end.remove(char)
            start.remove(char)

    return [start, end]

def next_iter(current_path, nodes, next_update_position):
    # current_path cannot be empty
    if next_update_position == len(current_path):
        # what to do if we want to update the next word
        next_char = current_path[-1][-1]
        # print(f'next char is {next_char}')
        if next_char in nodes and len(nodes[next_char]) != 0:
            current_path.append(next_char + nodes[next_char][0])
            nodes[next_char].pop(0) # remove this char so that it cannot be used again
            return [current_path, nodes, next_update_position+1]
        return [current_path, nodes, next_update_position-1] #dead end: now try to replace the last word
    else:
        if next_update_position != len(current_path) - 1:
            print('Something wrong here') #update should be either for a new element or the last element
            return False
        # what to do if we want to replace last word
        starting_char = current_path[-1][0]
        prev_try = current_path[-1][-1]
        nodes[starting_char].append(prev_try) # put the previous try back into nodes
        nodes[starting_char].sort()
        current_path.pop() # remove last item
        for item in nodes[starting_char]:
            if item > prev_try: # assumes everything is alphabetically sorted
                current_path.append(starting_char+item)
                nodes[starting_char].remove(item)
                return [current_path, nodes, next_update_position+1]
        # No more replacement options for 
        if next_update_position == 0:
            return False
        else:
            return [current_path, nodes,next_update_position-1]

def find_path(string_list):
    nodes = list_to_nodes(string_list)
    start, end = get_mismatches(string_list)

    if len(start) > 1:
        print('More than one mismatched letters. Does not work!')
        return False
    if len(start) == 1:
        start_char = start[0]
    else:
        start_char = string_list[0][0] #start with first (ie random) starting character

    path = [start_char + nodes[start_char][0]] #initialize path
    nodes[start_char].pop(0) #remove char
    position = 1 # 0th element already filled. now start with first

    while True:
        result = next_iter(path, nodes, position)
        if result == False:
            print("There's no solution!!!")
            return False
        else:
            path, nodes, position = result
            # print(f'path is {path} and position is {position}')
            if position == len(string_list):
                restored = []
                temp_list = string_list.copy()
                for item in path:
                    current = next(word for word in temp_list if word.startswith(item[0]) and word.endswith(item[1]))
                    restored.append(current)
                    temp_list.remove(current)

                return restored
```

I have the following helper methods to help generate some lists and test the code:

```
def gen_random_words(num, len):
    # generate a list of random strings where num is number of strings and len is length of each string
    # you may or may not be able to find a workable path in the list (as it's totally random)
    result = []
    for _ in range(num):
        temp = ''
        for _ in range(len):
            temp += random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
        result.append(temp)
    return result

def gen_sequential_words(num, len):
    # generate a list of random strings where num is number of strings and len is length of each string
    # you will be able to find a workable path
    result = []
    last = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    for _ in range(num):
        temp = last
        for _ in range(len-1):
            temp += random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
        last = temp[-1]
        result.append(temp)
    random.shuffle(result)
    return result

def test_sequence(string_list):
    # test if a list of string are in sequential order (ie last char of one word matches first char of next word)
    # purpose of this method is to double check the output from find_path() is indeed correct
    for i in range(0, len(string_list)-1):
        if string_list[i][-1] != string_list[i+1][0]:
            return False
    return True
```

These are the test:

```
# test 1: generate 10000 random words. should not work
test1 = gen_random_words(10000,4)
find_path(words)
```

And another one:

```
# test 2: generate 10000 random words. should work
test2 = gen_sequential_words(10000,4)
answer = find_path(test2)
print(test_sequence(answer))
```

To test the speed:

```
%%timeit
find_path(test2)
2.93 s ± 64.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Thoughts welcome!

Comment: Yea, for `samples = ['ok', 'ok']` also StopIteration

Comment: Just realized there's some flaw with my logic. Will delete my answer... sorry!

Comment: Edited my answer... took a while but think it works now!

Comment: @fuzzy_logic so your logic is fuzzy after all

Comment: Can’t blame me for not giving a disclaimer... =)

Comment: Yes wrote it to be case sensitive, but obviously an easy fix if meant to be case insensitive... underlying algo doesn't change. =)