# Find arrays from an array of arrays of numbers in which one or more elements are equal

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search, find

Exists array with arrays those contains numbers.
How to find and concatenate arrays where one or more elements are equal with preserving the sequence.

For example:

```
Input: [[1, 2], [4, 3], [2, 7], [3, 5], [5, 9]]
Output: [[[1, 2], [2, 7]], [[4, 3], [3, 5], [5, 9]]]
```

Comment: There are many questions about the exact same problem asked on stackoverflow already. Suggested keywords to find these questions: "hamiltonian path", "sort list of edges", "domino sequence", "path from list of edges"

Comment: Note that your input defines a directed graph, where each distinct integer represents a vertex of a graph, and each pair of integers represents a directed edge (also called an arc).

Comment: You should also clarify in your question whether one integer can appear more than twice in your list; for instance, could you have `[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [1, 4], [4, 9]]`? If so, then in general the problem is equivalent to finding a hamiltonian path in a graph, which is NP-hard; but if not, then the problem is easy and there are efficient algorithms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if exists any path, in DI-Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64681887/check-if-exists-any-path-in-di-graph)

Comment: @Stef, yes, one integer can appear more than twice, but
This input can be: ```[[1, 2], [5, 7], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]```
This input cant be: ```[[1,2], [5, 7], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]```
During iteration, if an element in the sequence disappears, it cannot reappear. PS. It is difficult to explain

Comment: btw, mind any method/codr u had tried?